# Empty and write html to Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write html but it says empty is not a function. I usually do this. I empty and then write something on the div.

```js
var status = $('#terminalStatusDiv');

 status.empty().html('<span class="terminalStatus">Connected</span>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="terminalStatusDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code is not working as it is right now is because you used "status" as a variable name and it is a Global Property.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status

```js
var status1 = $('#terminalStatusDiv');

 status1.empty().html('<span class="terminalStatus">Connected</span>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="terminalStatusDiv"></div>
```

Comment: it has nothing to do with jQuery. It's a [global property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status).

Comment: there's no such thing as reserved words in jquery or javascript, there are just predefined variables and properties, etc

Comment: Thanks for the link I added it.

Answer (score 1):

[status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) is built in javascript keyword

```
var foo = $('#terminalStatusDiv');

foo.empty().html('<span class="terminalStatus">Connected</span>')
```